# Change the hierarchical parent

Tags: java, android

I have and activity (say A) which gets started by another activity (say B) which itself gets started by the main activity. Now most of the time the back button in A should take you back to B. But there are circumstances which A gets started by the main activity. Although I tested it and it works as I want it, but makes the hierarchical parent irrelevant.

Since the hierarchical parent of A is B, should I avoid starting A by another activity rather than B?

- if the answer to is yes is there a way to change the hierarchical parent in Java?
- if the answer is no, then what's the point of the hierarchical parent? The back button just takes you back to the activity which started the current activity anyway.

EDIT:

First of all thanks for the replies.

So from what I understood, now that when I start activity A from the main activity, I should make sure that the Up button takes me to activity B, regardless of what activity started A, right?

Comment: the notion of temporal and ancestral parent is explained in details here http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link it would be helpfull.

http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html

---

As they say, a picture says a thousands words:

[image]